# Grayscale QPushButton with QIcon until hovered over

Tags: python, pyside2, qpushbutton

I have a `QPushButton` that has a `QIcon` set. I would like to grayscale the icon's colors until it is hovered over or selected, without writing 2 separate image files for each icon. If use `QPushButton.setDisabled(True)` the icon's colors do in fact turn to grayscale, so I would like this same behavior being controlled through a `enterEvent`. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you described. Enable the button in the `enterEvent` and disable it in the `leaveEvent` if it's not checked.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setDisabled(True)
        self.setIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setEnabled(True)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.isChecked():
            self.setDisabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    grid = QGridLayout(w)
    grid.addWidget(Button(), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I used a green check mark for the icon image. Result:

[image]

You also don't *need* to subclass QPushButton, this will work too.

```
btn = QPushButton()
btn.setCheckable(True)
btn.setIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
btn.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))

btn.setDisabled(True)
btn.enterEvent = lambda _: btn.setEnabled(True)
btn.leaveEvent = lambda _: btn.setEnabled(btn.isChecked())
```